# Non EU citizen with German Residence Permit Transit in London

Tags: visas, uk, transit, paperwork, transit-visas

I have an Indian passport and I'm currently working in Germany.

I am travelling from Dusseldorf--London Heathrow--Chennai. Transit time in London Heathrow is 1 hour 30 minutes, and connecting flight to Chennai departs on the same day and it is also from the same terminal.

I have a German residence permit(Aufenthaltstitel), and my German visa is type "D".

Could you please let me know if I require a transit visa in London?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a German residence permit, you do **not** need a visa. A D visa also exempts you from that.

Comment: can you provide a source for this information